# How to merge two execute two reactor fluxes in parallel that return lists and merge the results

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have a LegacyAccountDto that I need to build a list of from two separate sources.  One is a local JPA repository and the other is a web service call.  The web service version has the accountStatus available where the JPA data source does not.  I need to execute two calls in parallel as Fluxes, and then when they both complete, I need to find the legacyId of the web service list and populate the list with the accountStatus pulled from the web service.  The whole idea is to return a list with the completed DTO.  I don't need to save it back to the web service or the JPA repo

The DTO:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class LegacyAccountDto {
  private UUID id;
  private UUID organizationId;
  private String name;
  private String website;
  private Long legacyAccountId;
  private LocalDateTime legacyCreated;
  private String accountType;
  private String accountState;
}
```

Each function in the merge statement returns a Flux of LegacyDTO

```
Flux<LegacyAccountDto> completed = Flux.merge(
      getLegacyAccountsFromSvc(accountNames),
      Flux.fromIterable(accountMapper.accountListToLegacyAccountDtoList(accountRepository.getAccountsByNames(accountNames).get()))
    )
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .???????((list1, list2) -> {
      list2.map(l2 -> {
        //find list1 by legacyId
        //set l2.accountStatus = l1.accountstatus
      })
      //return the completed list as a flux
    })
```

I'm not sure what function to call next to be able to have access to both lists and grab the accountStatus out of the second call and be able to merge it and have it not be returning a parallel flux type rather than just the Flux of LegacyDto

Comment: Do you have an example of both input lists and what the expected output should be?

Comment: Basically I have them both returning the same DTO listed above.  The JPA call returns everything except the accountState property, and the webservice call returns everything except the UUID (id).  So I basically need to loop through one list and add the missing pieces where the "name" property matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
Mono<List<LegacyAccountDto>> firstMonoList = getLegacyAccountsFromSvc(accountNames).collectList();
Mono<List<EntityX> secondMonoList = accountMapper.accountListToLegacyAccountDtoList(accountRepository.getAccountsByNames(accountNames).get()).collectList();

Mono.zip(firstMonoList, secondMonoList)
.map(listTuple -> {
  // do the searching and map to list of dtos
  return resultingList;
})
.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```

It's not advised to use blocking database calls in reactive flow. If you have the option you could add the `R2DBC` driver and make the whole thing reactive.

Comment: I'm pretty new to reactive and started a job recently after a 10+ year hiatus from Java... Why using a Mono for a List?  And how would I access the values in listTuple?

Comment: Oh, that is a long time for a break. So for Fluxes that are not neverending you receive a completed signal and you can then collect them all in a list. Since you do not know which item in first flux matches to which item in second flux you must have all elements to construct your resulting flux. The tuple has two methods getT1() and getT2() which return a respective list.

Comment: Trying this out - but I'm slow because I stink at reactive

Comment: This worked, but we wound up deciding to migrate the data rather having to look up this data across two services.  Thanks for the help!